# Is there a permutation of a given length in which every element divides sum of the elements before it?

Tags: number-theory, permutations

For given positive integer $n$, is it possible to construct a permutation $p$ of [1, n],  such that for each $k$ in
[2, n], $p_k$ divides $p_1 + p_2 + ... + p_{k-1}$.

Solutions for small $n$:

$n=3$, p = 2 1 3

$n=4$, p = 4 2 3 1

$n=5$, p = 4 1 5 2 3

$n=6$, p = 4 1 5 2 6 3

$n=7$, p = 5 1 6 2 7 3 4

$n=8$, p = 5 1 6 2 7 3 8 4

$n=9$, p = 8 1 9 6 4 7 5 2 3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $p = (x + 1, 1, x + 2, 2, \ldots)$, with $x = \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor$. It's not hard to check that $p$ is indeed a permutation and the condition holds.

Comment: Should that be $\lceil \frac n2 \rceil$ instead of $\lfloor \frac n2 \rfloor$?